# How to change cell text to bold or colored if the date is today?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I change cell text to bold or colored if the date is today?
And change the 6 cells below it to bold as well?

Comment: You'll get more constructive, positive help if you show what you have tried.  We don't even know if your cell text is a date.  Is this a programming question or just conditional formatting?

Comment: ok. sure.
the first cell is a date
the 6 cells below it are plain text
and what I want to do that every day=today those cell will change their colors and/or get a bold text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be achieved with a single formula if you select the range to be applied to **and** six rows at the top. Select the range to apply to plus six rows above that. Then Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., Custom formula is:

```
=or(A1=today(),offset(A1,-1,)=today(),offset(A1,-2,)=today(),offset(A1,-3,)=today(),offset(A1,-4,)=today(),offset(A1,-5,)=today(),offset(A1,-6,)=today())
```

and Done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your date cell in A1.  Right-click on your date cell, select conditional formatting.  Here you can see that you have an option for date is equal to today, select whatever formatting.

Do the same for the cell 6 below, but select 'Custom formula is', type in the formula `=A1=today()`, select your formatting.

You can copy and paste this formatting just like anything else.  You can choose the range for this formatting in the conditional formatting menu as well.